# Custom yaml configuration in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having some trouble loading custom configuration data from a yml file. I've looked at a few resources and can't seem to get anywhere with it.

When I try to load some custom settings from the yml file I get an empty hash.

my application.rb contains:

```
config.myapp = config_for(:myapp)
```

my myapp.yml contains:

```
default: &default
  emails:
    support: test@myapp.com
    marketing: marketing@myapp.com
    address: 123 Test lane

production:
  <<: *default

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

When I call:
    Rails.configuration.myapp

I get:

```
{}
```

Any thoughts what the issue might be?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with your yaml, so it has to be rails configuration, can't help you with that, I'm a sinatra man. Does the extension need to be .yml or .yaml ?

Comment: Your file `myapp.yml` must be located in the `config/`, folder as the [doc specify](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/config_for).

Comment: I checked and double checked and it is in the config folder :)

Comment: Dammit ^^, I think this line `(YAML.load(ERB.new(yaml.read).result) || {})[Rails.env] || {}` is where you got trouble. Maybe check your `Rails.env` or try to load your yaml file in a rails console to debug what could go wrong. Anyway good luck

Comment: What happens when you do `Rails.application.config_for(:myapp)` in your console?

Comment: Would you believe it worked after I restart my macbook? I wonder if this might have been a spring issue?

Comment: @rubyist ["Have you tried to turning it off and on again?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Answer (score 1):

It's got something to do with the lifecycle of the Application object and where your `config.myapp = config_for(:myapp)` call sits.

So I tried it locally and solved this problem by putting it inside a config.before_initialize callback block:
this is in my `config/application.rb` file

```
config.before_initialize do
  config.myapp = config_for(:myapp)
end
```

and then in rails console `Rails.application.config.myapp` correctly dumps the config parsed from yml.